# Take non-zero elements in a macro-list

Tags: python, list

I have a problem with the instruction `np.nonzero()` in python. I want to take all the indices of a given list that are non zero. So, consider that I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import binom
M=4
N=3
def generate(N,nb):
        states = np.zeros((int(binom(nb+N-1, nb)), N), dtype=int)
        states[0, 0]=nb
        ni = 0  # init
        for i in xrange(1, states.shape[0]):
            states[i,:N-1] = states[i-1, :N-1]
            states[i,ni] -= 1
            states[i,ni+1] += 1+states[i-1, N-1]
            if ni >= N-2:
                if np.any(states[i, :N-1]):
                    ni = np.nonzero(states[i, :N-1])[0][-1]
            else:
                ni += 1
        return states
base = generate(M,N)
```

The result of `base` is given by:

```
    base = [[3 0 0 0]
 [2 1 0 0]
 [2 0 1 0]
 [2 0 0 1]
 [1 2 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 2 0]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 0 2]
 [0 3 0 0]
 [0 2 1 0]
 [0 2 0 1]
 [0 1 2 0]
 [0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 0 2]
 [0 0 3 0]
 [0 0 2 1]
 [0 0 1 2]
 [0 0 0 3]]
```

The point is that for a given index `j,k` I want to take all the items in `base` that has non-zero components in the sites `j,k`, for example:

Taking `j=0,k=1` I have to obtain:

```
result = [1 4 5 6]
```

which corresponds to the elements 1,4,5,6 of `base` that satisfies this condition. On the other hand, I have used the command:

```
np.nonzero((base[:, j]) & (base[:, k]))[0]
```

but it doesn't work correctly, any idea why?

Comment: there is a shift in the result, you forget [3 0 0 0].

Comment: yes sorry, i edit this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the syntax for list index `base[:, j]` is wrong, use : `[:][j]` instead

also:

```
np.nonzero((base[:, j]) & (base[:, k]))[0]
```

won't work ,because the `&` sign is not applicable here..

you could use numpy like this:

```
b = np.array(base);
j=0;k=1;
np.nonzero(b.T[j]* b.T[k])[0]
```

which will give:

```
array([1, 4, 5, 6])
```